# URL Keyword density checker API

Tags: c#, api, keyword

Is there any free API to check keywords density of an url (or html doc)? I need to it works with non-English urls too.

This is an example of keyword density checker but without api:
http://tools.seobook.com/general/keyword-density/

If there is no free API, a C# library can be alternative solution for me too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATED**

Heres the https://dotnetfiddle.net/g40YQ3

I'm not sure about a free API, but its pretty simple to do it in C#.

Request the HTML.

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    string html = client.DownloadString("http://stackoverflow.com/").ToLower();
}
```

Remove HTML elements with a regular expression. You can modify it to remove other elements for instance `<style>` element just add `<style[^>]*>[\s\S]*</style>` with the `|` character.

```
public static string RemoveHtmlTags(string html)
{
    string htmlRemoved = Regex.Replace(html, @"<script[^>]*>[\s\S]*?</script>|<[^>]+>|&nbsp;", " ").Trim();
    string normalised = Regex.Replace(htmlRemoved, @"\s{2,}", " ");
    return normalised;
}

//remove html elements
html = RemoveHtmlTags(html);
```

Split the string by spaces

```
List<string> list = htmlCode.Split(' ').ToList();
```

Remove non alphabet characters with regex - *optional*

```
var onlyAlphabetRegEx = new Regex(@"^[A-z]+$");
list = list.Where(f => onlyAlphabetRegEx.IsMatch(f)).ToList();
```

further blacklist words (greater than 2 characters, not important, etc..) - *optional*

```
//add your own
string[] blacklist = { "a", "an", "on", "of", "or", "as", "i", "in", "is", "to", "the", "and", "for", "with", "not", "by" };
list = list.Where(x => x.Length > 2).Where(x => !blacklist.Contains(x)).ToList();
```

Then get the distinct keyword by key and count, and then order by count.

```
var keywords = list.GroupBy(x => x).OrderByDescending(x => x.Count());

foreach (var word in keywords)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", word.Key, word.Count());
}
```

This is a **very** simple example of how to find the keyword density, and can be improved on.

There is also a library called HtmlAgilityPack which helps somewhat with processing html elements.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it is a little more complicated. Html tags like this will not ignore: <a href='...'>. and also we need to extract keywords with two words and three words.

Comment: I have just updated my code with an example link. You can run it and it will showcase how to get a simple keyword density count of stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks Nick! I worked with HtmlAgilityPack, Its great! Do you have any idea about how to find 2 or 3 word keywords? I have to try all combination of words? for eg: "Hello, this is a nice day" then I have to check: "hello this", "this is", "is a", "a nice", "nice day".

Comment: You can pretty much use the code above to do that. Take the phrase and remove any non alphabet characters, then split the string up into a list. Create a flag that is set to false, Iterate through the list with the iterator at current position and at iterator+1 eg. phrase[iterator+1] and match that to the extracted html string after the elements have been removed (before splitting it up into a list). I hope that helps. Please accept the answer if it helped you get to your solution.